# Android アプリの UI で、 `ScrollView` の入れ子は可能か

Tags: android, scrollview

Android で `ScrollView` の入れ子をしたいと考えていますが、うまくいきません。

親の `ScrollView` が画面全体()で、子の `ScrollView` はその親のなかの一部という構成になりますが、そもそも可能なのでしょうか？

できれば XML を使用したいと考えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

可能ですが、タッチイベントを制御してやる必要があります。（xmlの設定だけではたぶん出来ません）

下記のページにその辺り詳しく書いています。
http://blog.lciel.jp/blog/2013/12/03/android-touch-event/